# SQL select not null values by default

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a sql sentence that might select rows when a field is not null, but if every field is null show me them.

Something like:

```
SELECT
field1, field2, field3
FROM
tableName
WHERE field1 = 
CASE WHEN field1 IS NOT NULL THEN 
    field1
ELSE
    null
END;
```

**Example:**

Having a table like:

```
 ______________________________________
|   field1   |   field2   |   field3   |
 --------------------------------------
|    null    |  TestData  |    123     |
|     23     |  TestData  |    123     |
|    null    |  TestData  |    123     |
 --------------------------------------
```

The result would be:

```
 ______________________________________
|   field1   |   field2   |   field3   |
 --------------------------------------
|     23     |  TestData  |    123     |
 --------------------------------------
```

But if data if every field1 is null:

```
 ______________________________________
|   field1   |   field2   |   field3   |
 --------------------------------------
|    null    |  TestData  |    123     |
|    null    |  TestData  |    123     |
|    null    |  TestData  |    123     |
 --------------------------------------
```

It should show every row

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Unclear, try to explain more what you want to achieve.

Comment: Looks like you want `COALESCE()` but I'm not sure I understand your exact specs... Could you please *edit* the question and provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With numbers:**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c07ae/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( field1, field2, field3 ) AS
          SELECT null, 'TestData', 123 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 23,   'TestData', 123 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT null, 'TestData', 123 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3
FROM   test
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                    FROM   test
                    WHERE  field1 IS NOT NULL )
OR     field1 IS NOT NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c07ae/1/0)**:

```
| FIELD1 |   FIELD2 | FIELD3 |
|--------|----------|--------|
|     23 | TestData |    123 |
```

**With only nulls:**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9694b/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( field1, field2, field3 ) AS
          SELECT CAST( null AS NUMBER(4) ), 'TestData', 123 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT null,   'TestData', 123 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT null, 'TestData', 123 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3
FROM   test
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                    FROM   test
                    WHERE  field1 IS NOT NULL )
OR     field1 IS NOT NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9694b/1/0)**:

```
| FIELD1 |   FIELD2 | FIELD3 |
|--------|----------|--------|
| (null) | TestData |    123 |
| (null) | TestData |    123 |
| (null) | TestData |    123 |
```

**--------Edit--------**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e1e94/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( field1, field2, field3 ) AS
          SELECT null, 'TestData', 123 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 23,   'TestData', 124 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT null,   'TestData', 124 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT null, 'TestData', 125 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3
FROM   test
WHERE  (
         NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                      FROM   test
                      WHERE  field1 IS NOT NULL
                      AND    field2 = 'TestData'
                      AND    field3 = 124
                    )
       OR field1 IS NOT NULL
       )
AND field2 = 'TestData'
AND field3 = 124
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e1e94/11/0)**:

```
| FIELD1 |   FIELD2 | FIELD3 |
|--------|----------|--------|
|     23 | TestData |    124 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3
FROM   test
WHERE  (
         NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                      FROM   test
                      WHERE  field1 IS NOT NULL
                      AND    field2 = 'TestData'
                      AND    field3 = 125
                    )
       OR field1 IS NOT NULL
       )
AND field2 = 'TestData'
AND field3 = 125
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e1e94/11/1)**:

```
| FIELD1 |   FIELD2 | FIELD3 |
|--------|----------|--------|
| (null) | TestData |    125 |
```

Comment: This approach is pretty good but doesn't solve my problem. See this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e1e94/4 It works when field3 = 124, but doesn't if 125

Comment: @JonathanCobo If one of the answers is correct you can accept it so the question gets closed (and upvote if appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
field1, field2, field3
FROM
tableName
WHERE (field1 is not null) or 
(field1 is null and field2 is null and field3 is null)
```